# Running a Python script from a Spring @Service

Tags: java, python, spring

I need to execute a python script with arguments passed from my user interface and display the results. I know how to do this using ProcessBuilder (below) but I presume that just calling this code from the relevant Spring @Service isn't a good idea (threading issues, too many instances running concurrently, etc). What would be the best approach?

```
@Override
public String executeLatestAlgorithm(String json) {

    try {
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("somescript.py", json);
        Process p = probuilder.start();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        return in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

(crap code without any significant errorhandling - just to illustrate)

Many thanks,

A

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Spring Integration provides support to execute scripts written in Python, JS, Groovy etc.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/cafe-scripted

Part of the Python related config XML looks as follows

```
<service-activator input-channel="hotDrinks"
    output-channel="preparedDrinks">
    <script:script lang="python" location="file:scripts/python/barista.py">
        <script:variable name="timeToPrepare" value="5" />
    </script:script>
</service-activator>
```